# Excluding one route from a *-binding on a RabbitMQ topic exchange

Tags: routes, rabbitmq, amqp

Given a RabbitMQ `topic` exchange, e.g. `x1` with a consumer queue bound like this:

```
"source": "x1",
"vhost": "rabbit",
"destination": "queue1",
"destination_type": "queue",
"routing_key": "A.*",
"arguments": {}
```

I now want to route some messages matching `A.*` to a different queue. For example, `A.a` should go to `queue2` while all other `A.*` should still land on `queue1`. The bindings for `queue2` will look like this:

```
"source": "x1",
"vhost": "rabbit",
"destination": "queue2",
"destination_type": "queue",
"routing_key": "A.a",
"arguments": {}
```

How should the bindings for `queue1` look like to exclude `A.a` but keep the rest? Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not what `topic` do, so if you have to use this type of exchange, you can't exclude one route from binding.

You may find [rtopic exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-rtopic-exchange) useful:

> The idea is to be able to specify routing patterns when publishing messages. With the default topic exchange patterns are only accepted when binding queues to exchanges.

Comment: To limit the change I would stick to the topic exchange and list all bindings explicitly, but this is a really good hint for the future.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't really make a routing key by saying "not this" or something similar.

To achieve what you want, you could try with a bit of a workaround: to set a big prefetch count to `queue 2` consumer and make sure that that consumer is the first to connect to the broker (because of round robin dispatch). You'd have to figure out to what to set the prefetch count to.

Of course, there are many reasons for this not to always work (what if consumers drops, or is too slow etc...)